# SQL Server table validation

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table which contains 17 columns. I need to perform validation on this table and if validation passes entries will set off to another tables.

I need to do following validations.

1. None of the column should contain any blank value (if it contains I need to track column name and row number)
2. One column say SSN number should not have duplicate entries (I cannot make it as primary key)

If any condition fails I need to get the column name and row number in first case and for `SSN` I need to know those SSN numbers

Kindly suggest.

Comment: I'd avoid duplicates on SSN with an unique constraint

Comment: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Unique_SSN ON dbo.YourTableName(SSN)` - no need to create a primary key just to enforce uniqueness!

Comment: @MiguelPrz: I cannot have any unique constraint on this table. This table is to accommodate what ever comes from end user excel file.